# Изменения размера кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-button

Есть кнопка размером `20dp` на `20dp`, после нажатия на кнопку, в кнопке меняется background, и должен изменится размер кнопки (`50dp` на `50dp`). Как это правильно реализовать? Размеры кнопки заданы в `xml` (`20dp` на `20dp`). Пробовала после нажатия на кнопку делать `mButton.setHeight(), mButton.setWidth()`, но такой способ не работает. Или просто нужно скрывать одну кнопку? И отображать другую?

Как это правильно делать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
int sizeInPX= (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
params.height = sizeInPX;
params.width = sizeInPX;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: П.С: методы setHeight(), setWidth() существуют.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, Точно, они есть у TextView, а я смотрел исходники Button.